# how to change color of a text item dynamically in d2k forms 6i?

Tags: oracleforms

I have been trying to change color of a field dynamically based on some conditions but it is not displaying correctly. Here is the code for that button:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR DATA IS
    SELECT EMPNO,ENAME,COMM FROM EMP;
BEGIN

    OPEN DATA;
    GO_BLOCK('BLOCK3');
    FIRST_RECORD;
    LOOP
        FETCH DATA INTO :BLOCK3.T_EMPNO, :BLOCK3.T_NAME, :BLOCK3.T_COMM;

        EXIT WHEN DATA%NOTFOUND;

        IF :BLOCK3.T_COMM IS NULL THEN
            SET_ITEM_instance_PROPERTY('BLOCK3.T_COMM',BACKGROUND_COLOR,'R255G70B70');
        --  message('comm is null');
        ELSE
        SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('BLOCK3.T_COMM',BACKGROUND_COLOR,'R255G100B70');
        --message('comm is not null');
            END IF;

        NEXT_RECORD;
    END LOOP;
    FIRST_RECORD;

END;
```

I have also tried to display the messages to see if query is working fine or not. Messages get displayed, but the color doesn't changes. All the fields are the same color.

Comment: Fastest way is to create another visual attribute and change it  with Set_Item_Property('BLOCK3.T_COMM',VISUAL_ATTRIBUTE,'RED');

Answer (score 1):

You should use visual attributes.
Just make a visual_attribute and then set the item to that visual attribute at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Create a visual attribute (for example VISUAL_RED with red foreground color) and then use

```
SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY(:SYSTEM.CURRENT_ITEM,CURRENT_RECORD,VISUAL_ATTRIBUTE,'VISUAL_RED');
```

If in multirow report then replace :SYSTEM.CURRENT_ITEM with 'BLOCK.ITEM'